# How to use a single instance of DbContext , per request using Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am refactoring a project that creates multiple DbCOntexts per method call in the data repositories.
So I want to have one instance of the DbContext per HTTP request.

I have tried to do:

```
container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

and for every repository:

```
...
container.RegisterType<IBusinessRepository, BusinessRepository>(new InjectionConstructor(new ApplicationDbContext()));
container.RegisterType<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();
...
```

But that will create a new instance of the DbContext() per repository, of course.

I tried

```
container.RegisterType<IBranchCategoryRepository, BranchCategoryRepository>(  
 new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

But that gives me:

> The PerRequestLifetimeManager can only be used in the context of an
>   HTTP request. Possible causes for this error are using the lifetime
>   manager on a non-ASP.NET application, or using it in a thread that is
>   not associated with the appropriate synchronization context.

So how can I inject the same instance to each repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Unity, but i am with various other IoC frameworks.

Why are you trying to set what to inject on the repositories?

```
container.RegisterType<IBusinessRepository, BusinessRepository>(new InjectionConstructor(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

Just leave out the DbContext here, but change it to:

```
container.RegisterType<IBusinessRepository, BusinessRepository>();
```

Because you did already register this component, it will be automatically injected in the constructor in each class that have a dependency. Your class should then look like this:

```
public class BusinessRepository : IBusinessRepository
{
   private ApplicationDbContext _context;

   public BusinessRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
   {
      this._context = context
    }
}
```

This works in Castle Windsor.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that, but I got an unhandled exception. After enabled API tracing I realized what was going on; there were other classes that had dependencies that was broken. I'll accept your answer, it made me look from it from another perspective.